# What open source spatial index libraries exist?

Tags: c#, java, .net, open-source, spatial-index

I am looking for a spatial index library in C# that has to be able to index geometries (circles, polygons, polylines) as well as answer intersection questions. I found NetTopologySuite (NTS) and some other one-file solution project but I wonder if I missed anything significant?

NTS is pretty good but somewhat heavy. The second one is a one man art and apparently I have to pick it up and maintain myself. I wonder if I can find something that is supported and tested.

I am looking for C# one but if I can get hands on Java one, I can adapt that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[libspatialindex](http://libspatialindex.github.com/) seems to have all the features you want, but it's in C++

[JSI](http://jsi.sourceforge.net/) is a Java project, but it only works with rectangles.

Comment: Adapting for other shapes may not be a problem as long as the search tree implementation is performant enough. That's basically the main thing - decent implementation of R-tree.

Comment: @Schultz9999: "Performant" is a rather relative term; I've used JSI and it was plenty performant enough for my purposes, supported a couple of thousand nearest neighbour lookups per second on a tree containing 80k elements, IIRC.

Comment: absolutely. That's what I meant - performant enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but i guess Solr and Elastic search supports spatial index. They are in Java and they support REST.

Answer (score 0):

I found some good examples here http://www.rtreeportal.org/